# Desaparecer texto en libgdx

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

Hola a todos estoy con android studio y estoy intentando hacer aparecer y desaparecer un texto.. por ahora tengo esto:

```
Container container1 = new Container(textLbl2);
        container1.setTransform(true);
        container1.center();
        container1.setPosition(Settings.GAME_WIDTH /2, Settings.GAME_HEIGHT /1 -textLbl2.getHeight()/1);
```

creo que la opción sería por ejemplo con ActionColor?

Por ejemplo tengo esta otra opción:( Que hace más grande o pequeño.. ) Necesito algo parecido pero con aparecer y desaparecer pero no lo consigo.. :(

```
    container1.addAction(Actions.repeat(RepeatAction.FOREVER, Actions.sequence(Actions.scaleTo(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f),Actions.scaleTo(0.2f,0.2f,0.2f))));
            stage.addActor(container1);

¡
```

Comment: Debes cambiar la visibilidad del elemento que agregas en el Container, en ete caso el Label textLbl2, deberías especificar el texto en que elemento se encuentra.

Comment: creo que lo he conseguido. Ahora pongo la solución!

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una posible solución:

```
Color color = Color.BLACK;
        Color color1 = Color.CLEAR;
        container1.addAction(Actions.repeat(RepeatAction.FOREVER, Actions.sequence(Actions.color(color, 1), Actions.color(color1,1))));
            stage.addActor(container1);
```

no sé si es la más correcta, pero consigo lo que necesito.